# Processing.js : how to draw() only parts of the canvas to reduce cpu usage

Tags: performance, draw, processing

Right now I have an html page that renders 20 canvases each with its own instance of a processing.js script. To decrease CPU usage, I have mouseover/out events to loop()/noLoop() only the graph the mouse is hovering over.

But I need to take this even further. The canvas right now is 300x400 where there is a 300x300 space that needs to dynamically draw all the time but there's a rectangle with a legend that is the rest of the space which really doesn't need to be redrawn using the framerate() of the rest.

Does any know of a way to essentially specify to the draw() function which pixels to redraw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a 100x300 blank area is not going to add significantly to the computations. But you can of course pass to draw something like:

`if(frameCount==1) [draw legend code];`

or using `if(frameCount % 30 == 0)...` for a continuous but less frequent rendering.

---

Edit:

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  noStroke();
  background(255);
}

void draw(){
  fill(255,255,255,50);
  rect(0, 150, width, height-150);

  if(frameCount%50 == 1) {
    fill(255);
    rect(0, 0, width, 150);
    fill(0);
    text("frame " + frameCount, width/2, 75);
  }
  fill(255,0,0);
  ellipse(random(0, width), random(150, height), 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: It's not a blank area. It's a legend which gets updated more or less once per second. I wanted to draw only on update but if I lower the framerate() then the entire canvas slows down. I was looking for a way to specify different framerates inside of a single canvas.

Comment: Sorry, but not really. See if I tell it to draw the legend only when the frameCount is 1, then it'll draw it once for a fraction of a second, and then from there on out, a blank space will appear in its place for the remaining of the playback. If I use your other option, it will flicker every 30 frames. What I need is to modify the draw function so that it STOPS redrawing based on, for example, pixels that I specify. That way I can do what you said and still keep the static legend from disappearing.

Comment: It will if you use a `background()` setting.  But there are alternatives - see the example I've added above..

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for persisting in trying to show me your solutions actually works! Turns out that code you just updated made me realize I was drawing the background in draw() (which I needed it to since I have balls bouncing around) So yeah, now it's working. You rock!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance